# Java: How to externally init an Enum without IF/SWITCH

Tags: java, enums

I have an Enum and I like to use it as a mapping between a symbolical name (NORMAL, SPICY, HOT) and its associated values (11, 22, 33).

Lets say the program should use the symbols and in the database are the values stored.

```
public static enum MyEnum
{ 
    NORMAL (11),        
    SPICY (22),     
    HOT (33);

    private int n;

    MyEnum (int n)    // must be a private constructor because of Java
    {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public static void initFromNumber (int n)
    {
        // ??? how to do that
    }

    public int get ()
    {
        return this.n;
    }
};
```

Now I read from the database and try to create/init the Enum.

How can I do that with an Enum (it is clear to me to do it with a class) **and** without having a big IF or SWITCH in it? Is there an "elegant" way?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Are you just trying to look up one of the enum values based on the number? Or are the numbers (11, 22, 33) going to change, and you need to set those in the enum, based on what's in the database?

Comment: `Enum`s are probably the most static structure in java, you can't really change them. What you can do is create a `Map<MyEnum, Integer>` which maps an enum to it's corresponding value from the database

Comment: You will not init the `enum`. Instead, you can create an `EnumMap` from the database and use that.

Comment: If you do just need to *find* one with a particular number, you can iterator over them using `MyEnum.values()`.

Comment: `Enum`s are initialized, like other classes, when they are first referenced in other code.  Or are you trying to look up which enum value corresponds to the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in my applications, I will loop over all of the values and find the matching one.

```
public static MyEnum getByNumber(int n) {
    for (final MyEnum value : values()) {
        if (value.n == n) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No MyEnum found for n: " + n);
}
```

Comment: This code is returning a value from a `void` method.

Comment: I believe the OP means that they want to set the numbers in the enum from a database rather than constant expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`Enum` is a singleton and you can not just initialize it. Most probably you want to get enum value by number. You can do this with stream:

```
public static void initFromNumber (int n)
    MyEnum enumValue = Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values())
            .filter(myEnum -> myEnum.get() == n)
            .findFirst().orElseThrow();
}
```

Comment: You never do anything with that `enumValue`. The method is void, and it's for a reason - the OP wants to use it to **set** numbers, not to **get** them.

Comment: @RealSkeptic *..I read from the database and try to create/init the Enum.* I guess the OP gets the number from database and wants to use symbols. *Lets say the program should use the symbols and in the database are the values stored.*